sudo apt install gcc fails
sudo apt install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  glade2script glade2script-python3 libllvm9 mokutil pastebinit syslinux-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu gcc-11-base gcc-13-base gcc-9 libasan5
  libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libgcc-9-dev libitm1
  liblsan0 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc gcc-9-multilib gcc-9-doc
  gcc-9-locales glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu gcc gcc-11-base gcc-13-base gcc-9 libasan5
  libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libgcc-9-dev libitm1
  liblsan0 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 3.257 kB/26,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 124 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.4.0-186.206
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::103 80]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gcc-11-base amd64 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 [19,3 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 [2.100 kB]
Fetched 2.119 kB in 34s (62,7 kB/s)                                                               
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-186.206_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::103 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

sudo apt install gcc fails

Your sources appear to be very outdated thus your problem... I quick scan and I'd expect your package to be linux-libc-dev | 5.4.0-189.209  | focal-security    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x which IS AVAILABLE, but without your outdated sources your machine isn't looking at what is available. I suggest running sudo apt update and correcting any issues there if available...

After you sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, do sudo apt install build-essential. That metapackage includes gcc and the supporting files and software.

Hello @waltinator and thanks for your interest in my question. sudo apt install build-essential fails with the same error.

As per first statement, your out of date sources will mean you have problems with many packages until you correct your issue via sudo apt update and correcting any warnings, errors or missing lines in the output there.  Your pasted detail shows a problem at that early stage.  Check your sources for missing detail & read apt update output for warnings/errors
